# AngularJS Documentation of .run() function

Tags: angularjs

I am working with angularJS routing. In this regard I need documentation of .run() function.What is the responsibility of .run() function.Thanks

Comment: You can find he AngularJS documentation at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#!)

> Run Blocks
>
> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run
>   block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It
>   is executed after all of the services have been configured and the
>   injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is
>   hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated
>   modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

run() is also the earliest you will have access to $rootScope.  It is a good place to register states and routes.